# execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException ( maximum trigger depth exceeded )

Tags: before-trigger, trigger

```
trigger UpdateContactField on Contact (after update) {
    Contact con;
    for(Contact c:Trigger.New){
        con=new Contact(id=c.id);
        con.Current_Company__c=c.Current_Company__c;
        con.Previous_Company__c=c.Current_Company__c;
        update con;
    }
}
```

I am new to Apex. While doing this i am getting following error:

> Error:Apex trigger UpdateContactField caused an unexpected exception,
>   contact your administrator: UpdateContactField: execution of
>   AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First
>   exception on row 0 with id 0032800000Lg9fQAAR; first error:
>   CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, UpdateContactField: maximum
>   trigger depth exceeded Contact trigger event AfterUpdate for
>   [0032800000Lg9fQ] Contact trigger event AfterUpdate for
>   [0032800000Lg9fQ] Contact trigger event AfterUpdate for
>   [0032800000Lg9fQ] Contact trigger event AfterUpdate for
>   [0032800000Lg9fQ] Contact trigger event AfterUpdate for
>   [0032800000Lg9fQ] Contact trigger event AfterUpdate for
>   [0032800000Lg9fQ] Contact trigger event AfterUpdate for
>   [0032800000Lg9fQ] Contact trigger event AfterUpdate for
>   [0032800000Lg9fQ] Contact trigger event AfterUpdate for
>   [0032800000Lg9fQ] Contact trigger event AfterUpdate for
>   [0032800000Lg9fQ] Contact trigger event AfterUpdate for
>   [0032800000Lg9fQ] Contact trigger event AfterUpdate for
>   [0032800000Lg9fQ] Contact trigger event AfterUpdate for
>   [0032800000Lg9fQ] Contact trigger event AfterUpdate for
>   [0032800000Lg9fQ] Contact trigger event AfterUpdate for
>   [0032800000Lg9fQ] Contact trigger event AfterUpdate for
>   [0032800000Lg9fQ]: []: Trigger.UpdateContactField: line 7, column 1

Basically What my requirement is, For the first time when i create a new record in contact, i enter a value for Current_Company__c field. when the second time i want to update the Current_Company__c field to some other value, then the previous value which was present in Current_Company__c should be updated to Previous_Company__c field.

Please help me.
Thanks and regards
KS Kumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing this in trigger, you can do this with process builder/workflow. Its always advisable to go with clicks not code.

Create a process on Contact object with criteria as ischanged of current company.

[image]

Create a immediate action to update the same record's previous company with priorvalue of current company.

[image]

Did a quick test and it works as intended.

If you really want to do this in trigger, this will help you.

```
trigger UpdateContactField on Contact (before update) {     
    for(Contact c:Trigger.New){
        if(c.Current_Company__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).Current_Company__c){
            c.Previous_Company__c=Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).Current_Company__c;
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. Changed your trigger to work on before update, as this won't require an explicit DML.
2. Added an if condition to check current company change. So previous company will populate only when current company changes.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah...... Thank you very much @Vigneshwaran G. You given one way to do this scenario. Its mostly helpful in the future. but I am new to Apex. So i wanna learn triggers also. Please give me suggestion in triggers also

Comment: Updated my answer with trigger code.